# How to find a substring count with Javascript and then pass into AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, angularjs-scope

Essentially what I want are numbers that I can pass into HTML based on a the number of times substring is matched from a response body.

I understand the best way to get that number is through regex. If I were to look for the number of occurrences of 'RED' for example I would want something like:

```
    var count1 = (proj.match(/RED/g) || []).length;
```

This is assuming that `proj` is a `var` with a response that has that in there.

Let's go with `proj` having too occurrences of 'RED'.

`count1` should equal '2' or so I believe it should. So I want this to be stored for use with AngularJS so I go:

```
    $scope.red = count1;
```

And in the HTML I add `{{red}}`. This however, does not show 2. It also does not break the AngularJS and the response is also fine.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Could you please share a fiddle reproducing your issue?

Comment: your count looks fine and as per your steps assuming you are doing a match with case sensitive red should display 2 share your code its may be somewhere wrong in your angular implementation

Comment: put `$scope.red = 'foo'`, if `foo` is rendered, then your problem is angularjs, not regex. for angulrajs, post your html and controllers setup